# Finding missing numbers in a preset range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having a problem finding missing values within a preset range.  For example I have:

Column A: 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11
I want either VBA or a formula in excel to return
Column B: 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 13 --> 30

The final number in Column B will vary.  I want it to change based on user discretion.  For my problem I am working with days of the month.  So January, February, and March have different total days.  I've seen a lot of examples, but all are based on a array in the spreedsheet.  What if I want to change the array to 1-30, 1-31, or 1-28 (depending on which month I am looking at)?

Comment: Could you share what you tried so far, and what you're getting stuck on.

Comment: Here is one that I tried from a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jel_Otcgds&t=75s)
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1),$A$1:$A$20,1,FALSE)),ROW(A1),"")

Comment: What I am looking for is to change the range that the formula or vba code is looking at, to a specific number I choose.  For example, from the video link above, they are choosing a range from 1-12.  I want the range to be from 1-30, but still only have those same numbers (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12).  So my missing numbers would be everything missing from 1-30.  I also want to make sure that the range starts at 1, even if my first value does not.

Comment: Please, do not post formulas or code in comments. Edit your question. Also, you've tagged the question as VBA, so post the code you've tried.

Comment: @Foxfire and Burns and Burns, okay, I will not make the mistake again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the formula quoted by OP in the comment above but generalised for user-defined number of numbers:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,C$2)),D$2:INDEX(D:D,COUNT(D:D)+ROW(D$1)),0)),
ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,C$2))),ROW()-ROW(A$1)),"")
```

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

**EDIT**

You can change the formula so that you can set both the start and end points:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(ROW(INDEX(A:A,C$2):INDEX(A:A,C$3)),D$2:INDEX(D:D,COUNT(D:D)+ROW(D$1)),0)),
ROW(INDEX(A:A,C$2):INDEX(A:A,C$3))),ROW()-ROW(A$1)),"")
```

This works with dates if column B is formatted appropriately:

[image]

Comment: Would this be possible to do with a date.  For example column B would be 3/4/2018, 5/4/2018 and column D would be 1/4/2018, 2/4/2018?

Comment: Yes, it would need a bit of adjustment to get the start date as well as the end date, but should work the same way.

Comment: Have added to answer

Comment: I am getting an error of `You've entered too few arguments for this function`.  the curser is between the double parenthesis after the 0, `ROW(D$1)),0))`.

Comment: However, I think I have found a much easier way.  I will autofill all of the dates starting with the known starting date (`A2`).  Then use the match function to show which dates have a match with the exclusions dates.  Dates with no match will result with a `#N/A`.

Answer (score 0):

this is how VBA code would be:

```
Option Explicit
Sub MissingNumbers()

    Dim C As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim FirstNumber As Long
    Dim LastNumber As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MyNumbers As New Scripting.Dictionary 'Need Microsoft Scripting Runtime library checked on references

    FirstNumber = 1 'here goes your first number to check
    LastNumber = 30 'here goes the last number to check

    'Assume you have a column A with all the values and column B will hold the missing ones
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'Change MySheet for your working sheet name
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row on column A
        'Store your existing numbers in the dictionary
        For Each C In .Range("A2:A" & LastRow) 'I'm assuming you have headers on row 1
            MyNumbers.Add C.Value, 1
        Next C
        LastRow = 2 'starting on row 2 for column B
        'Loop through all the numbers you want to check
        For i = FirstNumber To LastNumber
            'If the number doesn't exist on the dictionary
            If Not MyNumbers.Exists(i) Then
                .Cells(LastRow, 2) = i 'write it on the next available row for columnB
                LastRow = LastRow + 1 'add 1 number to last row so we don't overwrite results
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is an example:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ROW($A$1:$A$30),MATCH(0,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW($A$1:$A$30),$A$2:$A$7,0),COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,ROW($A$1:$A$30))),0)),"")
```

Confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can change this part `ROW($A$1:$A$30)` to your liking to include a larger range of numbers (or smaller) depending on the month.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowA As Long, LastRowB As Long, i As Long, StartValue As Long, EndValue As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    StartValue = 1
    EndValue = 30

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRowA)

        For i = StartValue To EndValue

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, i) = 0 Then

                LastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

                If LastRowB = 1 And .Range("B" & LastRowB).Value = "" Then
                    .Range("B1").Value = i
                Else
                    .Range("B" & LastRowB + 1).Value = i
                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a possible [formula solution](http://www.excelformeln.de/formeln.html?welcher=362) would be **ARRAY FORMULA:   CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
{=SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A:A,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)+1))+MIN(A:A)-1)=0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)+1))+MIN(A:A)-1),ROW())}
```

Copy downwards to get all values.